# Combining tryCatch with s3 custom errors

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to understand the example given in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R chapter 'Exceptions and Debugging'

Here is the example code:

```
condition <- function(subclass, message, call = sys.call(-1), ...) {
    structure(
        class = c(subclass, "condition"),
        list(message = message, call = call),
        ...)
    }

custom_stop <- function(subclass, message, call = sys.call(-1), ...) {
    c <- condition(c(subclass, "error"), message, call = call, ...)
    stop(c)
    }

my_log <- function(x) {
    if (!is.numeric(x))
        custom_stop("invalid_class", "my_log() needs numeric input")
    if (any(x < 0))
        custom_stop("invalid_value", "my_log() needs positive inputs")
    log(x)
}

tryCatch(
    my_log("a"),
    invalid_class = function(c) "class",
    invalid_value = function(c) "value" 
)
```

Wickham says "You can then use `tryCatch()` to take different actions for different types of errors."

But what is the point of the `tryCatch` statement here?

If I want the the `my_log` function to turn a negative value positive then return the log, I can just put the relevant code under the `custom_stop("invalid_value"...)` line.

My goal is just to be able to write functions which handle errors in a uniform and informative way.

Thanks for your time.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The key advantage of emitting custom conditions is that you let someone who doesn't want to modify the functions know how your function failed.  For example, suppose that you wanted your users to be able to react differently to different types of failure.  If you just used `stop` they would have no easy way to programmatically determine the nature of the failure.

For example, I can write code like:

```
x <- "1.1"
tryCatch(
  my_log(x),
  invalid_class=function(c) my_log(as.numeric(x)),
  invalid_value=function(c) my_log(abs(x))
)
```

Note the above is illustrative and isn't meant to be fully robust, and really, you would probably want to log any conditions that occur and not automatically try to circumvent the problems, but hopefully this illustrates how custom conditions can be useful to your users.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I can just summarise what's happening here:

Comment: Thanks.  So if I can just summarise what's happening here:
The my_log(x) function creates some custom conditions that will be shown to the calling function (or the console) if it's called in anything other than a 'tryCatch' type piece of code. 
However, when the 'my_log' function is called from a 'tryCatch' function, the 'tryCatch' code decides how to handle it. 

What you're saying is that the tryCatch, although it can decide how to handle the errors and warnings, is better suited to logging conditions rather than fixing them as your code may then miss some deeper bug.

Comment: @RobertEdwardArbon, yes mostly.  The code can do more than logging (and is perfectly suited for that), but should probably log in addition to whatever else it does unless the conditions under which conditions are issues are rigorously documented.